# SQL Query /stored procedure to get complete organization hierarchy detail

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I tried and searched the solution for the below problem statement but unfortunately I didn't get the exact output. I need to display the complete organizational hierarchy in the below format. I tried with using CTE with UNION ALL but still I'm unable to get the exact output.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPMASTER
(
    EMPID CHAR(10),
    EMPNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    EMPDESIG VARCHAR(20),
    MRGID CHAR(10)
);
```

Output:

```
EMPNAME     EMPID   EMP DESIGNATION
------------------------------------
EMP1    00001   CEO
EMP2    00009   MANAGER 1
EMP3    00005   TL1
EMP4    00003   SSD1
EMP5    00006   SD1
EMP6    00008   TL2
EMP7    00020   SSD2
EMP8       25   SD2
EMP9    00030   TL3
EMP10   00017   MANAGER2
EMP11   00029   TL4
EMP12   00045   SSD3
EMP13   00060   SSD4
EMP14   00070   SD3
EMP15   00060   SD4
EMP16   00090   SD5
EMP17   00055   SD6
CONTI…  CONTI…  CONTI…
```

Code that I tried:

```
WITH HierarchyTree (EMPID, EMPNAME, EMPDESIG, MRGID, Rank)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT 
        EMPID, EMPNAME, EMPDESIG, MRGID, 0 AS Rank
    FROM
        EMPMASTER AS e
    WHERE 
        DESIGNATION = 'Admin' AND EMPLOYEE_ID='1'

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT 
        e.EMPID, e.EMPNAME, e.EMPDESIG, e.MRGID, Rank + 1
    FROM 
        EMPMASTER AS e
    INNER JOIN 
        HierarchyTree AS d ON e.REPORTINGTO = d.EMPLOYEE_ID
)
SELECT 
    EMPID, EMPNAME, DESIGNATION, REPORTINGTO, Rank
FROM 
    HierarchyTree
```

Sample data

```
EMPID       EMPNAME     EMPDESIG    MRGID
1            RAM          CEO           0
7326         MOHD RAFI    MANAGER       7454
7454         PMT PHARMA   MANAGER       1
2094         VAC SANJAY   DEVELOPER     14005
602          GS           MANAGER       7454
412          RAJESH       LEAD          602
14005        VAC SM N     LEAD          7326
34395        DEEPAK       LEAD          7326
16430        VIJAY        DEVELOPER     34395
```

[image]

Comment: Well, show us your table structure (table names, column names + datatypes), and show us your code that you have now!

Comment: Thanks for your concern @marc_s, here is my table structure ....TABLE NAME :EMPLOYEEMASTER,---    COLOMNS ------ EMPNAME ->NVARCHAR(50),EMPID->CHAR(10),MGRID->CHAR(10),

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Marc_s ..Please do the need full..

Comment: Yes, and what SQL code have you tried so far? We'll help you fix any problems, but we're not just a code-writing service just writing everything for you .....

Comment: I am assuming the table structure you mentioned is of the input table? Can you give us one or two rows of that table? I can try helping you with this.

Comment: Is the order of the _exact output_ at each level, i.e. the left-to-right order in the tree, based on alphabetical sorting of the `EMP DESIGNATION`? If not, how is it determined?

Comment: @marc_s  updated the SQL code I have tried ,please do need full

Comment: @Deepanshu Kalra, i have updated sample data ,please do need full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would venture to suggest an answer based on the hierarchy diagram:

```
declare @EMPMASTER table
(
    EMPID     CHAR(10)     ,
    EMPNAME   NVARCHAR(50) ,
    EMPDESIG  VARCHAR(20)  ,
    MRGID     CHAR(10)
);

insert into @EMPMASTER values
( '00001', 'EMP1', 'CEO', null ),
    ( '00002', 'EMP2', 'MANAGER1', '00001' ),
        ( '00003', 'EMP3', 'TL1', '00002' ),
            ( '00004', 'EMP4', 'SSD1', '00003' ),
                ( '00005', 'EMP5', 'SD1', '00004' ),
        ( '00006', 'EMP6', 'TL2', '00002' ),
            ( '00007', 'EMP7', 'SSD2', '00006' ),
                ( '00008', 'EMP8', 'SD2', '00007' ),
        ( '00009', 'EMP9', 'TL3', '00002' ),
    ( '00010', 'EMP10', 'MANAGER2', '00001' ),
        ( '00011', 'EMP11', 'TL4', '00010' ),
            ( '00012', 'EMP12', 'SSD3', '00011' ),
            ( '00013', 'EMP13', 'SSD4', '00011' ),
                ( '00014', 'EMP14', 'SD3', '00013' ),
                ( '00015', 'EMP15', 'SD4', '00013' ),
                ( '00016', 'EMP16', 'SD5', '00013' ),
                ( '00017', 'EMP17', 'SD6', '00013' ),
    ( '00018', 'EMP18', 'MANAGER3', '00001' ),
        ( '00019', 'EMP19', 'TL5', '00018' ),
            ( '00020', 'EMP20', 'SSD5', '00019' ),
            ( '00021', 'EMP21', 'SSD6', '00019' ),
                ( '00022', 'EMP22', 'SD7', '00021' ),
                ( '00023', 'EMP23', 'SD8', '00021' ),
        ( '00024', 'EMP24', 'TL6', '00018' ),
            ( '00025', 'EMP25', 'SSD7', '00024' );

with cte as 
(
    select 
        EMPID    ,
        EMPNAME  ,
        EMPDESIG ,
        MRGID    ,
        LEVEL    = 0,
        PATH     = cast(EMPDESIG as varchar(8000))
    from 
        @EMPMASTER
    where
        MRGID is null

    UNION ALL

    select 
        t.EMPID    ,
        t.EMPNAME  ,
        t.EMPDESIG ,
        t.MRGID    ,
        LEVEL      = cte.LEVEL + 1,
        PATH       = cast(cte.PATH + ' > '+ t.EMPDESIG   as varchar(8000))
    from 
        @EMPMASTER t
        inner join cte on cte.EMPID = t.MRGID 
)
select 
    EMPID     ,
    EMPNAME   ,
    EMPDESIG  ,
    MRGID     ,
    LEVEL     ,
    PATH      ,
    HIERARCHY = replicate('     ', LEVEL) + EMPDESIG
from 
    cte 
order by 
    PATH;
```

The same but with the provided data samples:

```
declare @EMPMASTER table
(
    EMPID     CHAR(10)     ,
    EMPNAME   NVARCHAR(50) ,
    EMPDESIG  VARCHAR(20)  ,
    MRGID     CHAR(10)
);

insert into @EMPMASTER values
('1'       ,     'RAM'        ,  'CEO'        ,   '0'       ),
('7326'    ,     'MOHD RAFI'  ,  'MANAGER'    ,   '7454'    ),
('7454'    ,     'PMT PHARMA' ,  'MANAGER'    ,   '1'       ),
('2094'    ,     'VAC SANJAY' ,  'DEVELOPER'  ,   '14005'   ),
('602'     ,     'GS'         ,  'MANAGER'    ,   '7454'    ),
('412'     ,     'RAJESH'     ,  'LEAD'       ,   '602'     ),
('14005'   ,     'VAC SM N'   ,  'LEAD'       ,   '7326'    ),
('34395'   ,     'DEEPAK'     ,  'LEAD'       ,   '7326'    ),
('16430'   ,     'VIJAY'      ,  'DEVELOPER'  ,   '34395'   );

with cte as 
(
    select 
        EMPID    ,
        EMPNAME  ,
        EMPDESIG ,
        MRGID    ,
        LEVEL    = 0,
        PATH     = cast(EMPDESIG + ' (' + EMPNAME +')' as varchar(8000))
    from 
        @EMPMASTER
    where
        MRGID = '0'

    UNION ALL

    select 
        t.EMPID    ,
        t.EMPNAME  ,
        t.EMPDESIG ,
        t.MRGID    ,
        LEVEL      = cte.LEVEL + 1,
        PATH       = cast(cte.PATH + ' > ' + t.EMPDESIG + ' (' + t.EMPNAME +')'  as varchar(8000))
    from 
        @EMPMASTER t
        inner join cte on cte.EMPID = t.MRGID 
)
select 
    EMPID     ,
    EMPNAME   ,
    EMPDESIG  ,
    MRGID     ,
    LEVEL     ,
    PATH      ,
    HIERARCHY = replicate('     ', LEVEL) + EMPDESIG + ' (' + EMPNAME +')'
from 
    cte 
order by 
    PATH;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @lobodava  thank u very much ,it helped me Lot :-)